# Wrong coefficients when deriving Simpson's Rule using Richardson Extrapolation

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, extrapolation

Ok, so I am going with Wikipedia's definition of the Richardson Extrapolation, rather than the recursive definition that I know is floating out there. One step at a time.

Given $A(h)$ is an estimate of $A^*$ with order $n$ convergence, an improved estimate can be found using the following:

$$R(h,p) = \frac{p^nA(\frac{h}{p}) - A(h)}{p^n - 1}$$

I believe I understood the derivation, but the application is elluding me, so I decided to try finding Simpson's Rule using the composite Trapezoid Rule:

$$A(h/2) = \frac{h}{2}\bigg(\frac{f(x_0) + f(x_N)}{2} + \sum^{N-1}_{k=1}f(x_k)\bigg) $$

$$A(h) = h\bigg(\frac{f(x_0) + f(x_N)}{2} + \sum^{N/2-1}_{k=1}f(x_{2k})\bigg)  $$

Then

$$
\begin{align}
R(h,2) &= \bigg[2h\bigg(\frac{f(x_0) + f(x_N)}{2} + \sum^{N-1}_{k=1}f(x_k)\bigg) - h\bigg(\frac{f(x_0) + f(x_N)}{2} + \sum^{N-1}_{k=1}f(x_k)\bigg) \bigg] \frac{1}{3} \\\
&= \frac{h}{3}\bigg( f(x_0) + f(x_N) + 2\sum_{k = 1}^{N -1}f(x_k) - \frac{f(x_0)}{2} - \frac{f(x_N)}{2} - \sum f(x_k) \bigg) \\\
&= \frac{h}{3}\bigg(\frac{f(x_0)}{2} + 2f(x_1) + f(x_2) + \cdots + f(x_{N-2}) + 2f(x_{N-1}) + \frac{f(x_N)}{2}\bigg) \\\
& = \frac{h}{6}\bigg(f(x_0) + 4f(x_1) + 2f(x_2) + \cdots + 2f(x_{N-2}) + 4f(x_{N-1}) + f(x_N)\bigg) 
\end{align}
$$

**EDIT**:  Thanks to at Lutz' suggestion, I found half the culprit, and have edited my question. However, I am left with a factor of $h/6$ out front, that I believe is still incorrect.

Comment: In the second trapezoidal formula, the inner sum has twice as many terms, $2N-1$, that the $N-1$ in the first formula. Or perhaps you should write the middle sum in the first formula as $\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}f(x_{2k})$, so that then the second formula has $\sum_{k=1}^{2N-1}f(x_k)$.

Comment: @Lutzl you're right of course!

Comment: In the last step, if you extract $\frac12$, you should do it with every term of the sum. The factor $\frac h6$ is then correct, just check with $f(x)=1$.

Comment: @LutzL thank you for helping me with basic algebra, even though it is far beneath most people to help someone with such weaknesses. I struggle so much, and I think that's obvious, but you are always willing to help me through my most basic of questions.